# Cassandra table with MAP data type column

Tags: cassandra, pentaho

I'm new to Kettle Pentaho PDI. I have one task to migrate data from one Cassandra database to another Cassandra database table. 
If the table contains "MAP" data type, its not moving the data to target database. How do i move the "MAP" data type column to Cassandra database table with same "MAP" data type.

Comment: which cassandra and cqlsh version are you using ?

Comment: I am using cassandra 2.0.14

Comment: Show your table schema

Comment: Find table schema below, CREATE TABLE student (
  id TEXT
 ,TIME TIMESTAMP
 ,ipadd TEXT
 ,name TEXT
 ,changes map < TEXT ,TEXT >
 ,PRIMARY KEY ((id) ,TIME));